# JMagick setup problems with Eclipse in OS X - UnsatisfiedLinkError: no JMagick in java.library.path

Tags: java, eclipse, imagemagick, jmagick

I am having some trouble setting up my environment in Eclipse for ImageMagick via JMagick in OS X. I have no problems using the ImageMagick command line tools (display, convert, etc.) after installing, but am unable to set up JMagick with a Java project in Eclipse.

Steps taken:

1. Downloaded JMagick 6.4.0
2. Generated jar and libs through make process in the INSTALL document
3. Copied libJMagick.so and libJMagick-6.4.0.so from lib to /usr/lib/java
4. Added JMagick.jar to build path
5. Linked /usr/lib/java directory to JMagick.jar native source, recommended in the solution posted by trigoman at the following url: [JMagick Error when trying to load a file - UnsatisfiedLink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553415/jmagick-error-when-trying-to-load-a-file-unsatisfiedlink)
6. Created sample class that accesses JMagick and attempted to run in Eclipse. Exception reported:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no JMagick
>   in java.library.path
>   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1758)
>   at
>   java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
>   at
>   java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1045)
>     at
>   example.ImageRender.main(ImageRender.java:10)

Does anyone have any ideas what might be the underlying problem is?

Comment: Are you launching with `-Djava.library.path=...`?

Comment: @Viruzzo Yes, I've tried -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/java which is where libJMagick.so and libJMagick-6.4.0.so and a number of .dylib files reside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

edit: see my comment below about using im4java instead of JMagick.

I was having the same problem, but just got it working by following these sparse instructions:
http://wesleyli.blog.com/2011/09/01/install-jmagick-on-mac/

But note there's a couple typos; looks like Lion auto-correct problems.
So what I did was:

```
svn co https://jmagick.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/jmagick jmagick
cd jmagick/trunk
./configure --with-java-home=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current --with-magick-home=/usr/local/jmagick
sudo make all & sudo make install
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libJMagick-6.5.7.so /Library/Java/Extensions/libJMagick.jnilib
```

And now it works for me. :)

Comment: Great, thanks fith. After building the jnilib with those flags and referencing the native lib in Eclipse, I was able to get it to work.

Comment: No problem. 

For my own project I just recently switched to im4java, which doesn't use the JNI (poorly supported on Mac), is better / still developed (jmagick hasn't been updated since like 2009 or something), and is available in Maven repositories so I didn't even have to deal with compiling or installing anything myself. 

I also found the interface more straight forward, and saw some minor performance improvements.

Only caveat was having to set a system-wide PATH to ImageMagick executables in environment.plist to get it to work on my Mac dev box.

http://im4java.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @fith Can you help me about how to use im4java in android?

Comment: No, I can't, sorry. I've never touched Android.